# Proving that elementary row operations are preserved after multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

If $E$ is an elementary $n \times n$-matrix, show that if $A$ is any $n\times n$-matrix, then $EA$ is a matrix obtained by carrying out a single elementary **row** operation on $A$, and that $AE$ is a matrix obtained by carrying out a single elementary **column** operation on $A$.

I can write out the matrices $A$ and $E$, and I can conceptually see why the problem statement is true, but I just don't know how to *prove* it. How would you prove such a statement (i.e. generalize it for all $n$)?

Comment: If you want, you can use these formulations to _define_ what change an elementary row respectively column operation realises. Then there is nothing to prove.

Comment: Also your title does not really correspond to what you seem to be actually asking (and in fact does not seem to make much sense at all). There is nothing in particular "preserved" here.